# Anyone using InnerActive Ads - and how?

Tags: livecode

I saw the commercial library for iAd's from Monte but he isn't developping it anylonger due to the coming of InnerActive Ads in Livecode, right? So, I have created an InnerActive account and tried [the only lesson I found on Livecode Lessons](http://lessons.runrev.com/s/lessons/m/4069/l/68315-how-do-i-use-ads-in-livecode). That didn't work. So I posted a comment there which is awaiting moderation for quite some time now. I also mailed Inneractive, got a ticket replied, but no answer from them either.

If anyone has Ads with Inneractive running please tell/show us how you did it. I am calling *mobileAdRegister* with my appID and that seems okay. Then I try *mobileAdCreate* and *mobileAdSetTopVisible* and 'the result' tells me '*could not create ad*'. 
Dictionairy then tells me *the app does not have Internet permissions or the registered app key is not valid*. But I do check for internet connection and I'm sure I'm using my valid appID..

Regards, Amsterfrank

Answer (score 1):

I have tested ads in the current release of LiveCode and they do indeed seem to be broken.

The LiveCode quality control team is aware of this and are currently investigating what could be the cause of this. A report on this issue can be viewed here-

http://quality.runrev.com/show_bug.cgi?id=11224

A workaround for now is to use an older version of LiveCode. After running a few tests, the last version of LiveCode that does not exhibit the mobile ad bug is LiveCode 6.0.0. This is available to download from here-

http://downloads.livecode.com/livecode/

With that being said, I would recommend holding off until the issue is resolved in a more current releases as there have been many bug/enhancements to LiveCode since 6.0.0